# String works with grep in terminal but not script

Tags: xml, bash, shell, grep

This cmd works fine on terminal line on RHEL7

```
grep -oPm1 '(?<=<app my_id=")[^<]+"my_name=
"xyz"+[^>] test.xml
```

But if I insert the line into a .sh script like:

```
grep -oPm1 '(?<=<app my_id=")[^<]+"my_name=
'"$var"'+[^>] test.xml
```

Where
`$var="xyz"`

It returns as blank.

I will hopefully have the above cmd in a loop
where `var` is read from a text file.

Comment: It's quite confusing about your characters. Please edit it, with all half-width characters. Possibly you typed those with some kind of IME.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that your first command works fine, it uses "smart" quotes (`‘”`) instead of the "normal" ones (`'"`), and even if it didn't, there is no closing single quote.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I have updated original question; can you help please?

Comment: I think it could be to do with the xml format; but any escaping I've tried in the script hasn't worked.

Comment: On [how to parse XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Have you considered using an XML tool instead?

Comment: The command you say "works fine" still has no closing single quote, so it's probably not the command you're actually using. And there is a line break in the pattern, which grep can't handle with the options you're using.

Comment: Where’s the ‘ missing?

Comment: You also need to provide a sample of the XML you are trying to process and the result you are trying to achieve. Also, you'd better use an XML tool instead as @that other guy said. I would try `xmlstarlet`.